# Combining user seleted and auto generated colors in flot

Tags: flot

I would like to use both the user selected and auto generated data series coloring in combination such that when a new data series is added colors are auto generated but all other data series already plotted will remain the same color.

When first adding a new data series, I leave the color option empty so that a color is auto assigned.

When re-plotting I extract color information from the an existing plot before re-plotting

I then look at the resulting color map and reassign the same color to the corresponding data series when re-plotting.

The problem is that when I add data series serially in this way with a call to $.plot between each data series addition, I end up with multiple data series assigned to the same color.

Example:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>Color Test Harness</title>
        <script src="./lib/jquery.js"></script>
        <!--[if IE lte 8]><script src="../lib/excanvas.js"></script><![endif]-->
        <script src="./lib/jquery.flot.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>Test graph</h1>
        <div id="graph1" style="width:600px;height:300px;"></div>

<script type="text/javascript">
$(function() {

    var data = [ [1, 2], [2, 3], [4, 1] ];
    var plot = $.plot($("#graph1"), {}, {});
    function findColors() {
        var c = {};
        if(plot != null) {
            var series = plot.getData();
            for(var i = 0; i < series.length; i++) {
               var aSeries = series[i];
               c[aSeries.label] = aSeries.color;
            }
        }
        return c;
    }

    var all_data = [];
    for(var i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
        var colors = findColors();
        var dataObj = { 'label' : "data" + i, 'data' : data };
        all_data.push(dataObj);

        for(var j = 0; j < all_data.length; j++) {
            if(colors.hasOwnProperty(all_data[j].label)) {
                all_data[j].color = colors[all_data[j].label];
            }
        }
        plot = $.plot($("#graph1"), all_data, {});
    }
})
</script>
    </body>
</html>
```

How can I get the color generator to make sure it uses a color that isn't already pre allocated to one of the other data series?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The colors are just numbers, an index really.  So when you are doing the `findColors()` thing, make an object that tracks which colors are already in use (i.e. right now you have label -> color, also make one that is just color -> 1).  Then, later when you are creating new series, have a little function that goes through your `colorsUsed` object and looks for an unassigned color index:

```
var colors = findColors();

var colorsUsed = findUsedColors(colors);

function findUsedColors(c){
    var cu = {};

    $.each(c,function(k,v){
       cu[v] = 1;
    });
    return cu;
}

function findUnassignedColor(cu){
    for (var i=0;i<2000;i++){
      if (!cu[i]){
         cu[i] = 1;
         return i;
      }
    }
}


// then later, when assigning a color
   for(var j = 0; j < all_data.length; j++) {
        if(colors.hasOwnProperty(all_data[j].label)) {
            all_data[j].color = colors[all_data[j].label];
        } else {
            all_data[j].color = findUnassignedColor(colorsUsed);
        }
    }
```